# Select lowest value within a table MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, subquery

I would like to get the `id_product_attribute` from the lowest price in the following table:

```
id_product | id_product_attribute  | price
210        | 131                   | 44.950000
210        | 132                   | 39.550000
210        | 134                   | 22.820000
210        | *135                  | 18.250000
211        | 137                   | 36.230000
211        | *138                  | 28.980000
```

The closest I got was with this query:

```
SELECT
    id_product,id_product_attribute,MIN(price) as price
FROM product_attribute 
WHERE price IN(
        SELECT MIN(price) 
        FROM product_attribute 
        GROUP BY id_product)
GROUP BY id_product
```

Although is succeeds in getting the lowest value (something asked my times here), it does not return te correct `id_product_attribute`. I tried some `ORDER BY`'s in the subquery, but that doesn't work for me either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to get the lowest price per `id_product`, don't you? Your query looks like it, but the text does not mention it.

Comment: Yes you're right. That would be optimal. However, what I have works good now. If you care to share, please add something to this :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subquery needs to select min(price) **AND** id_product, and since that's two fields, you'll have to join against a derived table, since you won't be able to use an `in()` match anymore:

```
SELECT *
FROM product_attribute AS pa
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id_product, MIN(price) as price
    FROM product_attribute
    GROUP BY id_product
) AS minprices
   ON pa.id_product = minprices.id_product 
       AND pa.price = minprices.price
```

Comment: Very nice, I learned new MySQL skills because of you. I got it to work as follows. 
`SELECT *
   FROM product_attribute AS pa
   LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT id_product, MIN(price) as price
     FROM product_attribute
     GROUP BY id_product
    ) AS min_price
   ON 
    pa.id_product = min_price.id_product 
   AND
    pa.price = min_price.price`